# Need explanation of how passing SSRS multi-value parameters to SQL works

Tags: sql-server, parameters, ssrs-2012, udf

I inherited several SSRS reports from someone who is no longer with the company.  The reports pass multi-value parameters to a SQL stored procedure.  That SP then uses a split function in the WHERE clause to read the values.  On some of the parameters the SSRS SP uses the `Join(Parameters!field.Value,",")` in order to properly pass the string values to SQL.  But it does not do this with all the multi-value parameters.

Can someone explain why the `Join()` would be needed in some multi-value parameters but not others?  I recently had to debug one report that was not populating all the data and found I needed to add the `Join()`.  But other reports seem to work fine without it.

Comment: Answer would lie in how the `Join()` function is defined.

Comment: Can you be any more specific?

Comment: Is it always the same SP which is used? I would guess that the JOIN() is always required when the SP performs a SPLIT()...

Comment: It's not always the same SP, but they don't look very different and they all use the SPLIT().  I would have also thought that the JOIN() was always required, but I'm finding ones where there is no JOIN().  I'm thinking I should always use the JOIN() when using the SPLIT().

Answer (score 0):

Join is needed when passing multi-value parameters to stored procedures that only accept 1 parameter for that field. When only one option from a list is selected no join is required, but when selecting multiple values they need to be joined into a single parameter, passed into the stored procedure, and then split inside the stored procedure. It only needs to be split once inside the stored procedure if the different values need to be treated individually.

I would recommend reading [this article on passing multi-value parameters to stored procedures](https://munishbansal.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/passing-multi-value-parameter-in-stored-procedure-ssrs-report/).

Comment: I'm still not sure why some of the multi-value parameters use the Join() but others do not.  If the user is selecting multiple values then I would expect a Join(), but that is not always the case here.  The SP's I'm working with are all written the same way and all use the same split function.

Comment: I would need to see the statement from SSRS and the data type for the multi-selects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question. Why not change the SP to Where IN (@var) get rid of the split.

Comment: Because SSRS will pass a separate variable for each variable selected in the multi-select but stored procedures expect a specific amount of variables. You can default variables to null and put logic in the SP to ignore null variables, but it is easier to join them, pass them in as one, then split them when in the SP.

Comment: Change the SP to expect a varchar(max) for that variable. Instead of running the sp over and over for each independent value.

Comment: If you selected "a", "b", and "c" from a mutli-select and joined it, it is passed as "a, b, c". Using an IN clause now will only compare to a single coalesced value of the ulti-select values selected. It also makes it difficult when comparing INTs and Dates. It is the difference between
    IN ('a, b, c')
and
    IN ('a', 'b', 'c').

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't able to help It works for me. But we don't know all of the variables involved.

Comment: Andrew's explanation is spot on.  I can't just use IN(@var) with SSRS.

Comment: You can split @var on ', ' and insert each value into a table variable, then use IN(SELECT VALUE FROM @TABLE), which is where the split comes in, but it is still based on the values being joined.